# Assign a value to a String variable in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables

I am trying to assign values to String variables ***within*** an array:

```
String details = "passFirst0,passLast0,Molly,Quinn";
Passenger passenger = new Passenger(details);

public class Passenger {

    private String firstNameField;
    private String lastNameField;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Passenger(String details) {
        String[] temp = details.split(",");
        String[] fields = {firstNameField, lastNameField, firstName, lastName};

        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < fields.length; ctr++) {
            fields[ctr] = temp[ctr];
        }

        // Print instance variables - all null
        System.out.println(this.firstNameField);
        System.out.println(this.lastNameField);
        System.out.println(this.firstName);
        System.out.println(this.lastName);

        // Print array - has values
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));
    }

    // Methods
}
```

However, the instance variables themselves remain null, while the `fields[]` has values when you iterate through the array.

Why is this so and how to accomplish this?

Comment: It's an array of strings, not an array of string variables. You can't have an array of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String objects are immutable - you cannot change their value - while doing assignments you are changing object to which the variable (or variable at given array index) is referring to.

When you do:

```
String[] fields = {firstNameField, lastNameField, firstName, lastName};
```

you set reference of `fields` array value with `index` 0 to same object that `firstNameField` is referring to (in this case `null`), `index` 1 to refer to same object as `lastNameField`, etc.

Then, if you do:

```
fields[ctr] = temp[ctr];
```

you are **not** changing value of the object `fields[ctr]` was referring earlier (one of your instance variables) to value of temp[ctr], but rather you are setting `fields[ctr]` to refer to the same object `temp[ctr]` is referring to right now.

If you want to refer to your variables as an array, why won't you just declare them as an array from the beginning?

Comment: Upvoted. Let's just say the `details` is being read from an external file. :)

Comment: While Andreas' solution is a close contender, I'm choosing this as accepted answer for detailed explanation of "why". Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against this, but you could use Java 8 method references:

```
public class Passenger {

    private String firstNameField;
    private String lastNameField;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Passenger(String details) {
        List<Consumer<String>> setters = Arrays.asList(this::setFirstNameField,
                                                       this::setLastNameField,
                                                       this::setFirstName,
                                                       this::setLastName);
        String[] temp = details.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < setters.size(); i++) {
            setters.get(i).accept(temp[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getFirstNameField() {
        return this.firstNameField;
    }

    public void setFirstNameField(String firstNameField) {
        this.firstNameField = firstNameField;
    }

    public String getLastNameField() {
        return this.lastNameField;
    }

    public void setLastNameField(String lastNameField) {
        this.lastNameField = lastNameField;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Passenger [firstNameField=" + this.firstNameField +
                        ", lastNameField=" + this.lastNameField +
                        ", firstName=" + this.firstName +
                        ", lastName=" + this.lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

*Test*

```
String details = "passFirst0,passLast0,Molly,Quinn";
Passenger passenger = new Passenger(details);
System.out.println(passenger);
```

*Output*

```
Passenger [firstNameField=passFirst0, lastNameField=passLast0, firstName=Molly, lastName=Quinn]
```

Answer (score 1):

They are null because they haven't been set, you can set them like this;

```
public class Passenger {

private String firstNameField = "a";
private String lastNameField = "b";
private String firstName = "c";
private String lastName "d";
```

Or with arguments to the `constructor` like this;

```
public Passenger(String details, String f, String l, String fn, String ln) {

   firstNameField = a;
   lastNameField = l;
   firstName = fn;
   lastName = ln;

   .....
}
```

As stated in the comments, you do overwrite the array values within the for loop, but you try to print out class members;

```
System.out.println(this.firstNameField);
System.out.println(this.lastNameField);
System.out.println(this.firstName);
System.out.println(this.lastName);
```

which are uninitialised.

Why not set the array like below;

```
String[] temp = details.split(",");
    String[] fields = {temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]};
```

And why bother with the other variables, just create `getters` for each needed variable, eg;

```
public String getFirstName() {
   return fields[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in "fields" you have the values of the split of "details" that you set in the for loop and in the instance variables you have nothing (They weren't initialized with data)

Comment: While this is true, this does not explain the full problem since OP overwrites the array fields within the `for` loop.

Comment: exactly, Strings are not an objects, it's a reference to an object

Comment: @Turing85 I see, I was overwriting the array. Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do in the for loop (i.e. assign the values to the instance vars themselves via loop)?

Comment: you may try to use reflection

Comment: @silver ther is no "easy solution" for this. There are ways (or more like hacks) to do so, e.g. reflection mentioned by Raz) but they are not worth it.

Comment: @silver No, and why do you need to? What's so difficult about writing `firstNameField = temp[0]; lastNameField = temp[1]; firstName = temp[2]; lastName = temp[3];`? It's really not that much more code than you have.

Comment: It's an experiment and learning about String and array properties. People can go easy on the downvote. Geez. Thanks for addressing the question, Turing85 and Raz. :)

Answer (score 0):

As for the "how", I ultimately went with Andreas' first comment:

```
public Passenger(String details) {
    String[] temp = details.split(",");

    this.firstNameField = temp[0];
    this.lastNameField = temp[1];
    this.firstName = temp[2];
    this.lastName = temp[3];
}
```

Realizing the simplest approach ain't so bad.